# How to install C# application?

Tags: c#, ado.net, installation

My mom has small library (cca. 500 books) and she asked me if I can make some program so she can organize those books. I have made simple C# application with couple of WinForms. But first, I have made database on SQL Server and imported it in my app using ADO.NET Entity Data Model. She can basicly do basic CRUD (Create, read, update, delete) operations with books.
Now I have two questions:

1. I need to install my app on my mom's computer (Windows XP) but I don't know how. I have searched on internet for some tutorials, but nothing useful there.
2. Do I need to install SQL Server on my mom's computer or my app will work without SQL Server when I install it?

Please help me

Comment: To be completely honest, it appears that you do not yet master the craft of software development enough for this and your mom would probably be happier with some off-the-shelf software such as Book Organizer (see http://www.collectorz.com/book/book_organizer.php). Just my 2 cents. And no, if you write software to use SQL Server, it will not work without it.

Comment: It is clearly obvious in my post that I am newbie in C# programming, but thanks for pointing it out, Roy. :)
No way I will buy that software. Thank you for "trying" to help.

Answer (score 1):

To install your app you need a setup creator. You can use the inbuilt one in visual studio or any of the following

- [Create Install](http://www.createinstall.com/)
- [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/)

and a host of others.

And no you dont have to install SQL Server on your mum's computer but you have to attach your database to the installer using Custom Actions

Comment: @MahirDuraković Glad i could help and by the way Pls dont call me `Sir`